# POST Request working in Postman but not in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, http, python-requests, postman

I had a Python script that would automatically add tickets to your basket on https://tickets.liverpoolfc.com/PagesPublic/Home/home.aspx

Now the script won't work, yet the same request works fine in Postman.
The request section works like this:

```
addheaders = {'origin': "https://tickets.liverpoolfc.com",
              'upgrade-insecure-requests': "1",
              'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
              'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36",
              'accept': "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"}

body={'__VIEWSTATE':'/wEPDwUJMzkxOTk4MjAyD2QWAmYPZBYCZg9kFgICAw9kFgJmD2QWCAIDDw8WAh4HVmlzaWJsZWhkZAIHDw8WAh8AaGRkAhEPDxYCHwBoZGQCIQ9kFgICAQ9kFgICCQ9kFgQCHQ9kFgICAQ9kFgRmD2QWHAIBD2QWAgIBDxYCHgRUZXh0BRhTZWxlY3QgQnkgU3RhbmQgYW5kIEFyZWFkAgMPFgIfAWVkAgUPFgIfAQUNVGlja2V0IEZpbHRlcmQCBw8WAh8AZxYKAgEPFgIfAQUUV2hhdCBpcyB5b3VyIGJ1ZGdldD9kAgMPDxYCHwEFDU1pbmltdW0gUHJpY2VkZAIEEBAPFgYeDkRhdGFWYWx1ZUZpZWxkBQVQcmljZR4NRGF0YVRleHRGaWVsZAUFUHJpY2UeC18hRGF0YUJvdW5kZxYCHghvbmNoYW5nZQXJAWRvY3VtZW50LmdldEVsZW1lbnRCeUlkKCdTaXRlTWFzdGVyQm9keV9Db250ZW50UGxhY2VIb2xkZXIxX3VzY1NlYXRTZWxlY3Rpb25fdXNjU3RhbmRBbmRBcmVhU2VsZWN0aW9uX2hkZlNlbGVjdGVkTWluaW11bVByaWNlJykudmFsdWU9dGhpcy52YWx1ZTsgUmVEcmF3U3RhZGl1bShmYWxzZSwgdHJ1ZSwgZmFsc2UsIGZhbHNlLCBmYWxzZSwgZmFsc2UpOxAVAQfCozIyLjAwFQEFMjIuMDAUKwMBZ2RkZAIGDw8WAh8BBQ1NYXhpbXVtIFByaWNlZGQCBxAQDxYGHwIFBVByaWNlHwMFBVByaWNlHwRnFgIfBQXJAWRvY3VtZW50LmdldEVsZW1lbnRCeUlkKCdTaXRlTWFzdGVyQm9keV9Db250ZW50UGxhY2VIb2xkZXIxX3VzY1NlYXRTZWxlY3Rpb25fdXNjU3RhbmRBbmRBcmVhU2VsZWN0aW9uX2hkZlNlbGVjdGVkTWF4aW11bVByaWNlJykudmFsdWU9dGhpcy52YWx1ZTsgUmVEcmF3U3RhZGl1bShmYWxzZSwgZmFsc2UsIHRydWUsIGZhbHNlLCBmYWxzZSwgZmFsc2UpOxAVAQfCozIyLjAwFQEFMjIuMDAUKwMBZ2RkZAIJDxYCHwBnFgYCAQ8WAh8BBRVQaWNrIGEgcHJpY2UgY2F0ZWdvcnlkAgMPDxYCHwEFFVBpY2sgYSBwcmljZSBjYXRlZ29yeWRkAgQQEA8WBh8CBQxQcmljZUJyZWFrSUQfAwUVUHJpY2VCcmVha0Rlc2NyaXB0aW9uHwRnFgIfBQXJAWRvY3VtZW50LmdldEVsZW1lbnRCeUlkKCdTaXRlTWFzdGVyQm9keV9Db250ZW50UGxhY2VIb2xkZXIxX3VzY1NlYXRTZWxlY3Rpb25fdXNjU3RhbmRBbmRBcmVhU2VsZWN0aW9uX2hkZlNlbGVjdGVkUHJpY2VCcmVha0lkJykudmFsdWU9dGhpcy52YWx1ZTsgUmVEcmF3U3RhZGl1bSh0cnVlLCBmYWxzZSwgZmFsc2UsIGZhbHNlLCBmYWxzZSwgZmFsc2UpOxAVAwALQUQvSlUgQVJFQVMKQURVTFQgwqMyMhUDATAFMTMyNjMFMTMyNTIUKwMDZ2dnZGRkAgsPFgIfAQUZU2VsZWN0IHRoZSBzdGFuZCBhbmQgYXJlYWQCDQ8WAh8BBRlXaGVyZSBkbyB5b3Ugd2FudCB0byBzaXQ/ZAIPDxYCHwBoFgICAhAQZGQWAGRkAhEPZBYIAgEPDxYCHwEFBVN0YW5kZGQCAhAQDxYIHgdUb29sVGlwZB8DBRBTdGFuZERlc2NyaXB0aW9uHwIFCVN0YW5kQ29kZR8EZxYCHghPbkNoYW5nZQXrA0phdmFzY3JpcHQ6IGRvY3VtZW50LmdldEVsZW1lbnRCeUlkKCdTaXRlTWFzdGVyQm9keV9Db250ZW50UGxhY2VIb2xkZXIxX3VzY1NlYXRTZWxlY3Rpb25fdXNjU3RhbmRBbmRBcmVhU2VsZWN0aW9uX2hkZlN0YW5kU2VsZWN0ZWQnKS52YWx1ZT10aGlzLnZhbHVlOyBMb2FkQXJlYXNGb3IxOExHQUModGhpcy5mb3JtKTtKYXZhc2NyaXB0OiBkb2N1bWVudC5nZXRFbGVtZW50QnlJZCgnU2l0ZU1hc3RlckJvZHlfQ29udGVudFBsYWNlSG9sZGVyMV91c2NTZWF0U2VsZWN0aW9uX3VzY1N0YW5kQW5kQXJlYVNlbGVjdGlvbl9oZGZBcmVhU2VsZWN0ZWQnKS52YWx1ZT1kb2N1bWVudC5nZXRFbGVtZW50QnlJZCgnYXJlYURyb3BEb3duTGlzdCcpLnZhbHVlO3ZhbGlkYXRlQXJlYURyb3Bkb3duKCk7SmF2YXNjcmlwdDogb25RdWFudGl0eUNoYW5nZWQoKTtKYXZhc2NyaXB0OiBSZURyYXdTdGFkaXVtKGZhbHNlLCBmYWxzZSwgZmFsc2UsIHRydWUsIGZhbHNlLCBmYWxzZSk7EBUFCUFueSBTdGFuZBJBTkZJRUxEIFJPQUQgTE9XRVIOS09QIEdSQU5EU1RBTkQQTUFJTiBTVEFORCBMT1dFUhBNQUlOIFNUQU5EIFVQUEVSFQUAAkFMA0tPUANNU0wDTVNVFCsDBWdnZ2dnZGRkAgQPDxYCHwEFBEFyZWFkZAIFEBAPZBYCHwUF+AFKYXZhc2NyaXB0OiBkb2N1bWVudC5nZXRFbGVtZW50QnlJZCgnU2l0ZU1hc3RlckJvZHlfQ29udGVudFBsYWNlSG9sZGVyMV91c2NTZWF0U2VsZWN0aW9uX3VzY1N0YW5kQW5kQXJlYVNlbGVjdGlvbl9oZGZBcmVhU2VsZWN0ZWQnKS52YWx1ZT10aGlzLnZhbHVlO0phdmFzY3JpcHQ6IG9uUXVhbnRpdHlDaGFuZ2VkKCk7SmF2YXNjcmlwdDogUmVEcmF3U3RhZGl1bShmYWxzZSwgZmFsc2UsIGZhbHNlLCBmYWxzZSwgdHJ1ZSwgZmFsc2UpOxAVAQhBbnkgQXJlYRUBABQrAwFnZGRkAhMPFgIfAGhkAhUPZBYEAgEPFgIfAGhkAgIPZBYIAgEPDxYCHwEFCFF1YW50aXR5ZGQCAw8PFgIeCU1heExlbmd0aAICFggeB29ua2V5dXAFFG9uUXVhbnRpdHlDaGFuZ2VkKCk7HwUFFG9uUXVhbnRpdHlDaGFuZ2VkKCk7HgNtaW4FATAeA21heAUCOTlkAgQPDxYIHgxFcnJvck1lc3NhZ2UFOlF1YW50aXR5IG11c3QgYmUgYmV0d2VlbiAwIGFuZCA5OSBmb3IgTEZDIEZPVU5EQVRJT04gRVZFTlQeDE1heGltdW1WYWx1ZQUCOTkeBFR5cGULKixTeXN0ZW0uV2ViLlVJLldlYkNvbnRyb2xzLlZhbGlkYXRpb25EYXRhVHlwZQEeDE1pbmltdW1WYWx1ZQUBMGRkAgYPDxYCHwEFA0JVWWRkAhcPFgIfAGhkAhkPFgIfAGdkAkEPFgIfAQWLFQ0KPHNjcmlwdCBsYW5ndWFnZT0iamF2YXNjcmlwdCIgdHlwZT0idGV4dC9qYXZhc2NyaXB0Ij4NCmZ1bmN0aW9uIExvYWRBcmVhc0ZvcjE4TEdBQyh0aGlzZm9ybSl7DQp2YXIgZGRsID0gZG9jdW1lbnQuZ2V0RWxlbWVudEJ5SWQoJ2FyZWFEcm9wRG93bkxpc3QnKTsNCnZhciBuZXdTdGFuZENvZGUgPSBkb2N1bWVudC5nZXRFbGVtZW50QnlJZCgnc3RhbmREcm9wRG93bicpLnZhbHVlOw0KaWYgKHRyaW0obmV3U3RhbmRDb2RlKSA9PSAiIikgew0KcmVtb3ZlQWxsT3B0aW9ucyhkZGwpOw0KYWRkT3B0aW9uKGRkbCwgIiIsICJBbnkgQXJlYSIpOw0KfQ0KaWYgKHRyaW0obmV3U3RhbmRDb2RlKSA9PSAiQUwiKSB7DQpyZW1vdmVBbGxPcHRpb25zKGRkbCk7DQphZGRPcHRpb24oZGRsLCAiIiwgIkFueSBBcmVhIik7DQphZGRPcHRpb24oZGRsLCAiMTIzIiwgIkJMT0NLIDEyMyIpOw0KYWRkT3B0aW9uKGRkbCwgIjEyNiIsICJCTE9DSyAxMjYiKTsNCmFkZE9wdGlvbihkZGwsICIxMjciLCAiQkxPQ0sgMTI3Iik7DQphZGRPcHRpb24oZGRsLCAiMTI4IiwgIkJMT0NLIDEyOCIpOw0KYWRkT3B0aW9uKGRkbCwgIjEyOSIsICJCTE9DSyAxMjkiKTsNCn0NCmlmICh0cmltKG5ld1N0YW5kQ29kZSkgPT0gIktPUCIpIHsNCnJlbW92ZUFsbE9wdGlvbnMoZGRsKTsNCmFkZE9wdGlvbihkZGwsICIiLCAiQW55IEFyZWEiKTsNCmFkZE9wdGlvbihkZGwsICIxMDgiLCAiQkxPQ0sgMTA4Iik7DQphZGRPcHRpb24oZGRsLCAiMTA5IiwgIkJMT0NLIDEwOSIpOw0KYWRkT3B0aW9uKGRkbCwgIjIwMiIsICJCTE9DSyAyMDIiKTsNCmFkZE9wdGlvbihkZGwsICIyMDciLCAiQkxPQ0sgMjA3Iik7DQphZGRPcHRpb24oZGRsLCAiMjA4IiwgIkJMT0NLIDIwOCIpOw0KYWRkT3B0aW9uKGRkbCwgIjMwNCIsICJCTE9DSyAzMDQiKTsNCmFkZE9wdGlvbihkZGwsICIzMDUiLCAiQkxPQ0sgMzA1Iik7DQphZGRPcHRpb24oZGRsLCAiMzA2IiwgIkJMT0NLIDMwNiIpOw0KfQ0KaWYgKHRyaW0obmV3U3RhbmRDb2RlKSA9PSAiTVNMIikgew0KcmVtb3ZlQWxsT3B0aW9ucyhkZGwpOw0KYWRkT3B0aW9uKGRkbCwgIiIsICJBbnkgQXJlYSIpOw0KYWRkT3B0aW9uKGRkbCwgIkwxIiwgIkJMT0NLIEwxIik7DQphZGRPcHRpb24oZGRsLCAiTDEwIiwgIkJMT0NLIEwxMCIpOw0KfQ0KaWYgKHRyaW0obmV3U3RhbmRDb2RlKSA9PSAiTVNVIikgew0KcmVtb3ZlQWxsT3B0aW9ucyhkZGwpOw0KYWRkT3B0aW9uKGRkbCwgIiIsICJBbnkgQXJlYSIpOw0KYWRkT3B0aW9uKGRkbCwgIlUxIiwgIkJMT0NLIFUxIik7DQphZGRPcHRpb24oZGRsLCAiVTIiLCAiQkxPQ0sgVTIiKTsNCmFkZE9wdGlvbihkZGwsICJVMyIsICJCTE9DSyBVMyIpOw0KYWRkT3B0aW9uKGRkbCwgIlU0IiwgIkJMT0NLIFU0Iik7DQphZGRPcHRpb24oZGRsLCAiVTUiLCAiQkxPQ0sgVTUiKTsNCmFkZE9wdGlvbihkZGwsICJVNiIsICJCTE9DSyBVNiIpOw0KYWRkT3B0aW9uKGRkbCwgIlU3IiwgIkJMT0NLIFU3Iik7DQphZGRPcHRpb24oZGRsLCAiVTgiLCAiQkxPQ0sgVTgiKTsNCmFkZE9wdGlvbihkZGwsICJVOSIsICJCTE9DSyBVOSIpOw0KfQ0KfQ0KZnVuY3Rpb24gTG9hZERlZmF1bHRzRm9yMThMR0FDKHN0YW5kRERMLCBhcmVhRERMKSB7DQp2YXIgdGhlU3RhbmRDb2RlID0gZG9jdW1lbnQuZ2V0RWxlbWVudEJ5SWQoJ3N0YW5kRHJvcERvd24nKS52YWx1ZTsNCnZhciB0aGVBcmVhQ29kZSA9IGRvY3VtZW50LmdldEVsZW1lbnRCeUlkKCdhcmVhRHJvcERvd25MaXN0JykudmFsdWU7DQpkb2N1bWVudC5nZXRFbGVtZW50QnlJZCgnU2l0ZU1hc3RlckJvZHlfQ29udGVudFBsYWNlSG9sZGVyMV91c2NTZWF0U2VsZWN0aW9uX3VzY1N0YW5kQW5kQXJlYVNlbGVjdGlvbl9oZGZTdGFuZFNlbGVjdGVkJykudmFsdWU9dGhlU3RhbmRDb2RlOw0KZG9jdW1lbnQuZ2V0RWxlbWVudEJ5SWQoJ1NpdGVNYXN0ZXJCb2R5X0NvbnRlbnRQbGFjZUhvbGRlcjFfdXNjU2VhdFNlbGVjdGlvbl91c2NTdGFuZEFuZEFyZWFTZWxlY3Rpb25faGRmQXJlYVNlbGVjdGVkJykudmFsdWU9dGhlQXJlYUNvZGU7DQpyZW1vdmVBbGxPcHRpb25zKGFyZWFEREwpOw0KYWRkT3B0aW9uKGFyZWFEREwsICIiLCAiIik7DQpzdGFuZERETC5zZWxlY3RlZEluZGV4PTA7DQp9DQpmdW5jdGlvbiB0cmltKHMpIHsgDQp2YXIgcj0vXGIoLiopXGIvLmV4ZWMocyk7IA0KcmV0dXJuIChyPT1udWxsKT8iIjpyWzFdOyANCn0NCmZ1bmN0aW9uIHZhbGlkYXRlQXJlYURyb3Bkb3duKCkgew0KLy8gaWYgdGhlcmUgYXJlIDIgb3B0aW9ucyBvbmx5IC0gaW4gYXJlYSBkcm9wZG93biB0aGVuIGJ5IGRlZmF1bHQgc2VsZWN0IHRoZSBzZWNvbmQgdmFsdWUgaW5zdGVhZCBvZiAiQW55IGFyZWEiDQppZihkb2N1bWVudC5nZXRFbGVtZW50QnlJZCgnYXJlYURyb3BEb3duTGlzdCcpLm9wdGlvbnMubGVuZ3RoID09IDIpIHsgDQpkb2N1bWVudC5nZXRFbGVtZW50QnlJZCgnYXJlYURyb3BEb3duTGlzdCcpLnNlbGVjdGVkSW5kZXggPSAxOw0KZG9jdW1lbnQuZ2V0RWxlbWVudEJ5SWQoJ1NpdGVNYXN0ZXJCb2R5X0NvbnRlbnRQbGFjZUhvbGRlcjFfdXNjU2VhdFNlbGVjdGlvbl91c2NTdGFuZEFuZEFyZWFTZWxlY3Rpb25faGRmQXJlYVNlbGVjdGVkJykudmFsdWUgPSBkb2N1bWVudC5nZXRFbGVtZW50QnlJZCgnYXJlYURyb3BEb3duTGlzdCcpLm9wdGlvbnNbMV0udmFsdWUgOw0KfQ0KfQ0KPC9zY3JpcHQ+ZAIBD2QWAgIBDxYCHwFlZAIgD2QWAgIEEBAPFgYfAgULUHJvZHVjdENvZGUfAwUSUHJvZHVjdERlc2NyaXB0aW9uHwRnZBAVAhNMSVZFUlBPT0wgViBXQVRGT1JEFExGQyBGT1VOREFUSU9OIEVWRU5UFQIGMThMSFdUBjE4TEdBQxQrAwJnZxYBAgFkZBgBBS5jdGwwMCRjdGwwMCR1c2NQZXJzb25hbGlzYXRpb25CYXJUb3AkTG9naW5WaWV3Dw9kAgFkHnzO56IhX/YZIlxUnOQWGCL0xwM=',
     'ctl00$ctl00$SiteMasterBody$ContentPlaceHolder1$uscSeatSelection$btnBuy':'Buy',
     'ctl00$ctl00$SiteMasterBody$ContentPlaceHolder1$uscSeatSelection$ddlGameSelection':'18LGAC',
     'ctl00$ctl00$SiteMasterBody$ContentPlaceHolder1$uscSeatSelection$hdfSelectedSeats':'MSU-U9/82/0251#A',
     'ctl00$ctl00$SiteMasterBody$ContentPlaceHolder1$uscSeatSelection$uscStandAndAreaSelection$hdfProductCode':'18LGAC',
     'ctl00$ctl00$SiteMasterBody$ContentPlaceHolder1$uscSeatSelection$uscStandAndAreaSelection$hdfProductPriceBand':'A'}

body = urllib.urlencode(body)

addreq = requests.post('https://tickets.liverpoolfc.com/PagesPublic/ProductBrowse/VisualSeatSelection.aspx?campaign=&product=18LGAC&productIsHomeAsAway=N&productsubtype=HOME&stadium=AS&type=H', headers=addheaders, data=body, verify=True)
```

I recieve a 200 status code, but the ticket is not added to the basket, however if I send this request through Postman then the ticket is added to the basket.

Comment: Is this a POST method or GET?

Comment: @skaul05 POST method, requests.post()

Comment: Can u show the code snippet where the post method of this API is written?

Comment: @skaul05 it’s the bottom line of code

Comment: I'm talking about the code of API which is storing data into the database.

Comment: @skaul05 sorry, I don’t know what you mean

Comment: You are not able to access via python requests bcz u might be using some authentication at POST API end.

Comment: @skaul05 there's no authorization needed, the request works fine in postman with no auth

Comment: Im talking about authentication not authorization.

Comment: @skaul05 how do I find out?

Comment: By looking at the code which enters the data passed via request into the database. I was talking about that code snippet.

Comment: @skaul05 this? https://pastebin.com/Fk2Ytxun